# Warum verwendet "einsteigen" den Akkusativ, "aussteigen" aber den Dativ?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Sie steigt in den Bus ein.
>
> Er steigt aus dem Bus aus.

Dies ließe sich von einer allgemeinen Regel für die Ausnahme von der Regel, dass Motion Akkusativ verwendet?

Comment: Es is nicht "ein-/aussteigen", die Akkusativ oder Dativ fordern, sondern "in" und "aus".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nein, die allgemeine Regel lautet: *Dativ* für die *Herkunftsangabe*, *Akkusativ* für *Richtungsangaben*.

> Sie steigt *von der Mole aus* (Herkunft) *in die Barkasse* (Richtung) ein.
>
> Er steigt *aus dem Bus* (Herkunft) *auf den Kantstein* (Richtung).

Welches Verb oder Verbgefüge genau verwendet wird, hat hier keine Auswirkung.

Comment: Mole, Barkasse, Kantstein? Das kenne ich als Muttersprachler nicht mal. Warum machst du kein Beispiel das jeder versteht?

Comment: Ich find's amüsant.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Kantstein ist Bordstein. Eine Barkasse könnte ich jetzt nicht zeichnen, aber entweder es ist ein kleiner Schiffstyp oder ein Behältnis für Münz- und Scheingeld, etwa auf dem Wochenmarkt. Eine Mole ist etwas Norddeutsches, küstenseitig. Es gibt einen Bahnhof Norddeich (Mole). "Damm in einem Hafen" sagt das Netz. Wie man davon aussteigen kann ist mir rätselhaft - ich hoffe es war dennoch etwas hilfreich.

Answer (score 4):

An sich ist es nicht etwa *das Verb*, sondern in erster Linie *die Präposition*, soweit vorhanden, die den Kasus regiert.

In deinem Fall also die beiden Präpositionen "in" und "aus".

"aus" ist simpel - Diese Präposition regiert grundsätzlich den Dativ.

"in" ist ein bißchen komplizierter, hier darf man sich zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ entscheiden.

Dativ kommt bei "in" zum Zuge, wenn es *einen Ort angibt, in dem etwas geschieht*, Akkusativ, wenn es *die Richtung einer Bewegung* angibt. In deinem Fall ist eindeutig das Zweite der Fall, also regiert "in" hier den Akkusativ.